# Publish to Artifactory copied from another project artifacts in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, artifactory, artifacts

So I got few separated jobs in Jenkins. The first one gets the project from a Git repository, builds it and produces artifacts. And another one has to copy certificates from the first job and publish them to Artifactory (tried to make it using the Artifactory plugin). But the thing is that the Artifactory plugin's available only in the Build job, there's nothing like "Generic-Artifactory integration" in second job's configuration.
Does anyone know what are the requirements for making the plugin work in the Publish job?

Comment: Have you tried the plug-in? https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=57182305

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write a small shell script leveraging [Artifactory REST API](http://wiki.jfrog.org/confluence/display/RTF/Artifactory%27s+REST+API) and execute it in your second, non-build job.

Comment: yeah, I've been thinking about that as well. I'll try this approach if there's no other way to implement that directly in Jenkins.

Answer (score 0):

I have done a similar thing with maven and a zip file. I have deployed a zip with a build step in maven calling a deploy:deploy-file and setting my Artifactory repository in settings.xml and deploying directly on my artifactory repository.